# CloudKit subscription with "CONTAINS" predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, icloud, cloudkit

I am trying to setup a CloudKit subscription based on testing membership in an array.

The code I'm using to create the subscription is as follows:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"users CONTAINS %@", userID];
CKSubscription *itemSubscription = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:@"foo"
                                                                predicate:predicate
                                                                  options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation|CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate];

CKNotificationInfo *notificationInfo = [[CKNotificationInfo alloc] init];
[notificationInfo setAlertLocalizationKey:@"Record notification"];
[notificationInfo setShouldBadge:YES];

[itemSubscription setNotificationInfo:notificationInfo];

[database saveSubscription:itemSubscription completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@, Subscription: %@", error, subscription);
}];
```

The log shows that the subscription is created successfully, however when I test by adding or changing a record via the CloudKit admin console I never get a notification on device.

I am able to receive notifications for subscriptions with other kinds of predicates (I've tested with a simple true predicate, and one that tests equality against a string field), so I know I have the notification code setup correctly.

I've also verified that my predicate listed above works when used in a fetch records query, so I know the predicate is setup correctly for the record type I have in CloudKit.

Has anyone been able to get subscription notifications with a predicate that tests for membership in an array?

Comment: Do you see the subscription listed in CloudKit dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

After playing around, I found that unless I set `notificationInfo.alertbody` the subscription never fired.

So try setting it to `"Test"` first, then after set it to `""`. I found it continued to work after I set it to a blank string (though I didn't try setting it blank to start with), and as a blank string it doesn't show a notification, but my handler still gets called, which was what I was after.

With iOS 8.1.1 / Xcode 6.1.1